# Perl 5.16 on windows 7 failed to install Template Toolkit

Tags: windows, perl, templates, installation, toolkit

I tried to install Perl 5.16 module 'Template-Toolkit' on windows 7 by using this command in cmd:

> C:>ppm install Template-Toolkit
>
> ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides Template-Toolkit

All other modules I installed (AppConfig, DBI, DBD-mysql, MailTools, GD, Chart, GDGraph, ..) succeeded.

Following [this webpage](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla%3aWin32Install) as a guide, they mention (under ActivateState Perl section) that you may not install Perl into a directory that contains a space (eg "C:\Program Files"), because it will break the Template-Toolkit installer. Since I installed Perl directly in 'C:\' -> 'C:\Perl64\', this could not be the case.

Is there a solution for this problem? Or should I use an older version of Perl, mentioned [here](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Template-Toolkit/)?

Answer (score 11):

The only errors in the error log are errors in the documentation (minor encoding issues). 
The module could be installed safely. Just use `cpan` to do it. You'll just have to force the installation.

```
C:\>cpan

cpan> install Template
```

For me, that runs without issue. (The failing tests are skipped since they're dev-only tests.) If if fails for you and the only failures are the two errors from t/zz-pod-kwalitee.t, you can safely follow up with

```
cpan> force install Template
```

Comment: I think that worked. It took about 10 minutes and had about 200 screens of output ;)

Comment: I got Warning and Error messages after above commands:

Warning: prerequisite AppConfig 1.56 not found.
Error from evaluation of C:\Perl64\cpan\build\Template-toolkit-2.24-TQ5QSS\xs/Makefile.PL: Could not load PERL_YAML_BACKEND 'YAML'
at C:/Perl64/lib/CPAN/Meta.pm line 320

Comment: Do you have the environment variable PERL_YAML_BACKEND defined? If so, then try to unset it.

Comment: @Khokhar, Try installing the YAML module

Answer (score 4):

According to the [ppm template-toolkit page](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Template-Toolkit/), the build for ActiveState's Perl 5.16 failed (which is why it isn't available).

Your options seem to be:

- Fix whatever bug is stopping it being built (it *looks* like it is just a couple of tests on the POD, so it could be an easy fix)
- Use an older version of ActiveState Perl
- Use a different distribution of Perl for Windows (such as Strawberry Perl)
- Use a different operating system (e.g. Ubuntu in a virtual machine)

Comment: Actually, no bug stops it from being built. See the earlier answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but you can get Template::Alloy from the ActiveState PPM: http://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Alloy which claims it supports the TT2 syntax among others.

Answer (score 0):

I got Warning and Error messages after these commands:

```
C:\>cpan
cpan> install Template
```

Please seen the screen shot below.

[image: Screen shot of Error and Warning message]